# About the subset of fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let R be any non-empty subset of closed under + and . Let S be a subset of R.Then any axiom of type (for all) which holds in (R;+;*) also holds in (S;+;*)—it is inherited. By contrast, an axiom of type (for some) may or may not hold on : it depends whether or not the element or elements whose existence in it guarantees actually belong to .
This is what I have seen in a book.
But I could not understand this.
Let say R is a set of real numbers.
Let a,b belongs to R.
Then (R;+;*) holds a closed set.
But when I consider a subset 0

Comment: Please edit your question, which seems to be severely mistyped. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

> it depends whether or not the element or elements whose existence in it guarantees actually belong to

Consider, for example, the field axiom "for every nonzero element, **there exists** a multiplicative inverse" .

Now $\mathbb Z$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb R$ that's closed under $+$ and $\cdot$. Does the axiom descend from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb Z$?

In contrast, things like the associative property, the distributive property and the commutative property of multiplication and addition all survive in subrings, passed down from the containing ring, and they use the **for all** quantifier.

Comment: But when I consider a subset 0<S<1,the closed set does not hold under addition because when I consider .9,.8 their sum 1.7 lies outside the set which contradicts the second line of the body.

Comment: @mechanics Right, it is not closed under addition. What is your point? The thing you cited only makes a claim about sets closed under $+$ and $\cdot$.  It doesn't say anything about a set like you just described.

Comment: @ rschweib then the set S does not form a feild right.Can you pls look at line 2 of the question that I have put,which states that if a R is a field then its subset is also a field.

Comment: @mechanics The last two lines of your post are incomprehensible.  Subsets of a field are hardly ever subrings, much less often fields...